# How to use CATKIN_IGNORE file correctly

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I have a catkin_ws that is composed of all the node for my project. I am working with a UAV. So some of the nodes (such as rqt_pluggins and other GCS nodes) doesn't need to be compiled on the UAV computer. My question is this, how to tell catkin make to ignore those package automaticly (yes I am aware of the command catkin_make -DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES="foo;bar" but it is not very usefull if i want to ignore 2 or more nodes)

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208180/how-to-use-catkin_ignore-file-correctly/) by [ETS-Dronolab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4112/ets-dronolab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use `CATKIN_IGNORE` for this, just create a file with that name in each of the package directories that you want catkin to ignore. You can use `touch` for that, ie:

```
touch /path/to/catkin_ws/your/package/CATKIN_IGNORE
```

If you now run `catkin_make` (or any of the other `catkin` variants), it should ignore any package in that directory (and also in all subdirectories). Note that if you already built your workspace before adding `CATKIN_IGNORE`, the pkgs might still be picked up by catkin, as it then uses some of the information in the `build` directory. Simply removing `build/` and `devel/` and rebuilding should fix that.

The new `catkin_tools` package supports so called *profiles*, which allow you to configure the black and whitelists in a more comfortable way (and also makes switching between them very easy).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-07-29**:
Which version onwards supports catkin tools?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-13**:
@2ROS0: it'd be better to open a new question for this, as it's rather unrelated to the one you comment on. But to provide you an answer: `catkin_tools` is not really tied to any particular ROS release, as it's a stand-alone tool. I'd expect it to work (best) with Indigo and up though.